# How do I solve this layout scenario involving a collapsible region?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following layout problem best explained here (apologies for the crude illustration)

[image]

Assume each control is implemented as a separate user control

I want behavior such that expanding the top right (green) control will render into view an expanded region wider than the initial (green) control's width and appear directly beneath it, with a width equal to the 2 controls in the first row (eg colspan of 2) while pushing down all the content beneath it

Assume initially there is a grid with 2 rows ..first row is some control and secondly the expandable control - the second row can have anything that will fill a colspan of 2 ..could be another layout container or user control with anything inside it etc.

If the green expandable control was a user control, what would I need to do to obtain this behavior I'm describing?

I'm thinking I need to set the Grid.Row and Colspan attached properties of the container representing the expanded content(?) from inside the user control to the layout grid the user control is inside? (but then how would I set the attached property of a control inside the user control to a layout container outside the user control - especially if the expanded content is itself inside a grid within the user control).

And even if I could do this, this would be very fragile since it would only work if the control was in a grid layout container.

Any ideas? Doesn't have to use a grid but that seems to be the natural / obvious way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar layout a while ago. This worked for me:

- On the green control, create dependency properties for the sizes you need. In this case, I expect the full width (lower rect) and the narrow width (upper rect).
- In the top-level container, you create a grid for measuring the sizes. So you'll get something like this:

  ```
  <Grid x:Name="fullSize">
       <ColumnDefinition/>
       <ColumnDefinition x:Name="halfSize"/>
  </Grid>
  ```

Here you can divide the width over the columns in the appropriate way.
- Then, bind the widths measured with this grid

```
   <foo:GreenControl
         FullWidth={Binding ElementName=fullSize, Path=ActualWidth}
         NarrowWidth={Binding ElementName=halfSize, Path=ActualWidth}
   />
```

Now the GreenControl can set its width to whatever it needs to be, e.g. in the handler for the value update. In my case I set bindings on the elements in the XAML to the dependency props.

Comment: Great start! And that solves the problem of getting the full width. Problem is, when my green control expands, I also need the additional expanded content to appear below it (eg the next Grid row) so there's two parts: the initial "minimal" green control still in the same place, then the expanded full width version that appears beneath it

Comment: Is that a fixed extra height, or depending on something in the green control? I would guess an extra row, then let the green control span two rows, and binding the height of the extra row to what the green control requires.

Comment: Let's say the extra content is fixed height for now - here's how I envision this: You have a UserControl ..it sits in a Grid in a Window. This Grid has 3 rows - 1 row for the UserControl, 2nd row which the expandable content in the UserControl will fill, 3rd row for the remaining window content. Inside the UserControl is another grid, in which sits the expanded content (let's say it's in a Stackpanel). When I expand I want to set the Grid.Row and Grid.Column attached properties on the StackPanel to reference the outer Grid in the window, outside the UserControl. Problem is - how do I set them?

Comment: You can do Grid.SetColumn(mygrid, colvalue); Grid.SetColumnSpan(mygrid, spanvalue); (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx about setting attached props).